# Captured variable from Slim route is undefined

Tags: php, variables, slim

I have the following slim route, but for some reason the `$cid` variable is not being recognized. The `$cid` var should be initialized from the first line of the code below where it says

`:cid`

and then it is used in the path variable of the response array further down.

`"path" => "/customers/".$cid."/vehicles/".$vehicle_id`

Here is the full code

```
$app->put('/customers/:cid/vehicles/?', function() use($app){

    $body = $app->request->getBody();
    $ds = getDataSource();

    $_PUT = array();
    parse_str($body, $_PUT);

    $vehicle_id = $ds->addVehicle( 
        $_PUT["owner"],
        $_PUT["year"],
        $_PUT["make"],
        $_PUT["model"],
        $_PUT["plates"],
        $_PUT["comments"] );

    if( $vehicle_id != null ){

        $response = array(
            "id" => $vehicle_id,
            "path" => "/customers/".$cid."/vehicles/".$vehicle_id
        );

        respond(200, $response);

    } else {
        $response = array(
            "Message"=> "Unable to add vehicle"
        );
        respond(400, $response);
    }
});
```

So i am a bit confused as to why I am getting:

```
Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:
    Type: ErrorException
    Code: 8
    Message: Undefined variable: cid
```

Anyone know why this is happening, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was not my brightest moment.

`$app->put('/customers/:cid/vehicles/?', function() use($app){`

should be

`$app->put('/customers/:cid/vehicles/?', function(`**$cid**`) use($app){`

The var must be passed to the closure.

derp.